# Begin Transaction not defined

Tags: php, sql

The begin transaction is undefined in mysql. Im actually using it to run multiple queries in my code to move a row from one table to another.  Much help will be appreciated. Okay my question is , Why is my Begin_transaction() not defined?

```
<?php 
    If(isset($trade_id)){
            $trade_id= $_GET['trade_id'];
    }
    require_once('connect.php');
    $mysqli = new mysqli($database_hostname, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name) or exit("Error connecting to database");
    try {
        // First of all, let's begin a transaction
        $mysqli->begin_transaction();

        // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `trade_history1` (session_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit, profitandloss, dateclose, close)
        SELECT session_id, trade_id, selection, date, type, size, bidprice, offerprice, stoploss, takeprofit, profitandloss, dateclose, close
        FROM `opentrades`
        WHERE `trade_id` = " . $tradeid);
        $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `opentrades` WHERE `trade_id` = " . $trade_id);

        // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
        // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
        $mysqli->commit();
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Successfully deleted';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // An exception has been thrown
        // We must rollback the transaction
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Unable to delete';
        $mysqli->rollback();
    }
    $mysqli->close();

            // if we successfully delete this, we 
            if ($successfullyDeleted) {
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'Successfully deleted';
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'Unable to delete';
            }

            header('Location: js.php');

    ?>
```

Comment: can you be more clear on the requirement ?

Comment: You have forgotten to ask a question.

Answer (score 7):

[PHP Manual](http://php.net) says *mysqli::begin_transaction* needs **PHP version 5.5.0** or upper (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php).

But you can use *mysqli::autocommit* instead (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php) with **PHP 5.x**:

```
//Begin transaction
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
...
//End transaction and auto commit
$mysqli->autocommit(TRUE);
```

Answer (score 5):

`$mysqli->begin_transaction();` must be `$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);`

Check this

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

Comment: This made the error go away but the deleting is not happening , what could be the problem?

Comment: For that you need to check the delete query

Comment: okay it managed to read the delete query but it is not running the insert query.

Comment: Can someone explain why PHP alludes to a method "begin_transaction" that actually makes sense, but doesn't define it, and instead uses "autocommit(FALSE)" which arguably makes less sense? This is driving me crazy!

Comment: begin_transaction() does not exist until php 5.5.0, please ensure that you actually have this version or higher if you wish to use this. instead, you can perhaps extend mysqli with your own class with a function added something like this:

    
   function begin_transaction()
   {

     /*this function is part of the mysqli object in 5.5 but isn't in 5.3 yet for example */
    if( phpversion() < '5.5.0' )
    {

     $this->query( 'START TRANSACTION' );
    
    }
    
    else
    {
     
     parent::begin_transaction( $flags, $name );
     
    }
  
   }

Comment: It is important to note that using autocommit may be problematic. If you are using connection pooling and your script execution fails after turning off autocommit, it might remain off for subsequent queries. This might mean that code you have later down the road which normally relies on autocommit might start to not work, or worse yet, you might start getting locking issues because a transaction never completes and thus never releases your tables, and other queries forced to wait. I may be wrong though, so you may wish to test this. I think this might only affect people who loop cron scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code i have tested.

> Object oriented style

```
$cid->multi_query('start transaction;');
$cid->multi_query("insert into demo values('1','Pankaj','9031251290')");
$cid->multi_query('commit;');
```

> Procedural style

```
mysqli_query($link, "start transaction;");
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('DEU', 'Bavarian', 'F', 11.2)");
mysqli_query($link, "commit;");
```

Comment: actually i  execute  multiple query at a time so i use this.